# Error while building a basic web crawler

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to run the following code for `web crawling`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def function1():
    url = "http://www.iitg.ac.in/"
    source_code  = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.findALL('a', {'target' : '_blank'} ):
        href = link.get(href)
        print(href)

function1()
```

but it is showing the following error:

```
File "C:/Users/HP/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 9, in function1
    for link in soup.findALL('a', {'target' : '_blank'}):

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I also checked for its solution on this platform already, but according to that there seems no un-callable object inside the function `findALL`.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no `a` element with `target="_blank"` in this page. You can make an `if` to assure you'll only iterate if `findAll` returned something.

```
def function1():
    url = "http://www.iitg.ac.in/"
    source_code  = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'target' : '_blank'} )

    if links:
        for link in links:
            href = link.get(href)
            print(href)
    else:
        print('No links found in page!')
```

Answer (score 0):

"Find All" function is case sensitive, either use `soup.find_all()` or `soup.findAll()`.

Otherwise, `soup.findALL` returns a `None` and then you're trying to call it..

Answer (score 0):

Your URL doesn't work for me.  Do you want to print all HREF elements from a URL?  Try the sample script below.

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.parse('http://www.gpsbasecamp.com/national-parks')
links = doc.xpath('//a[@href]')
for link in links:
    print(link.attrib['href'])
```

Result:

```
/contact-gpsbasecamp.php
/privacy-policy.php
/terms-of-service.php
/
                                National-Parks/map
/National-Historic-Parks
/National-Historic-Sites
/National-Monuments
/Other-NPS-Facilities
national-parks/Acadia_National_Park
national-parks/Arches_National_Park
national-parks/Badlands_National_Park
national-parks/Big_Bend_National_Park
national-parks/Biscayne_National_Park
national-parks/Black_Canyon_Of_The_Gunnison_National_Park
etc., etc., etc.
```